# ML method to identify data subset with lower average values

Tags: machine-learning

I have a task where I need to bin groups of observations [y,X] by the average value of y, using the feature set X.

A good interpretation is that these are customers and I want to find the most valuable ones.

One idea is decision trees, but I'm not sure this yields the optimal groups for my problem. My intuition is that decision trees mainly are used for prediction, so the focus of the algorithms might be different. Another idea is a brute force search.

Can someone give point me in the right direction with some concepts (maybe just search keywords) of how this problem is solved in ML?

Comment: Sounds like a classic example of clustering the data

Comment: I think that decision trees are your best bet here. Why do you think it's not 'optimal'?